# Attempting to display image names stored as a JSON array and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

I am creating a post creation page and in the form I store the image names in hidden form inputs then put them together in javascript to further send these through an ajax request to a PHP page that handles the information and stores it to the database, the problem is when I try to loop through the Array, I only get an "A" or the word "Array".   Here's my code:

Javascript where I collect the imagenames:

```
var imageNames = [];
images.find('span').each(function(){
    var imagename = $(this).text();
    imageNames.push(imagename);
});
JSON.stringify(imageNames);
```

here is the ajax request I use to send the data:

```
$.ajax({
            method:"POST",
            url:"php/publish.php",
            data:{xsthumb:xsimg, sthumb:simg, medthumb:medimg, Lthumb:Limg, images:imageNames, text:pubContent, desc:shortDesc, desc2:shortDesc2, cat:cat, section:sec, title:ttl },
            success:function(data){
                alert('data incomming');
                console.log(arguments);
                alert(data);
                window.location = '../';

            },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(arguments);
                 alert(errorThrown);
              }
        })
```

ImageNames is the variable where I suppose is the array, when I alert it in javascript it shows something like : "imagename.jpg, imagename.jpg"

This is how my Php file looks like:

```
//images
    $gallery_images = $_POST['images'];
    $gal_images = implode("," , $gallery_images);

$sql = "INSERT INTO posts(title, images, post, category, date_posted, visible, author_id, section) VALUES('$title', '$gal_images', '$article_text', '$category', '$today', '$visible', 'Moncho', '$section')";
    $qry = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die(printf(mysqli_errno($con)));
```

So when I go to the dynamic post page and try to pull the images I do this:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];


    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id= $id ");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        $title = $row['title'];
        $images = $row['images'];
        $text = $row['post'];
        $date = $row['date_posted'];
        $author = $row['author_id'];
        $section = $row['section'];
    };
    json_decode($images);
     for($i=0; $i < count($images); $i++){
        //echo '<a href="#" class="post-thumb">';
        //echo '<img src="images/post-img/'. $imgs;
        //echo '" alt="'.$title.'">';
        //echo '</a>';
        echo $images[$i];
    }
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing I assume the problem is somewhere between the ajax and the PHP, but that's just me...

Comment: **WARNING** your code is extremely vulnerable to sql injection attacks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to replace

```
json_decode($images);
```

with

```
$images = explode(',' , $images);
```

Exploring the problem: you're saving the data on the database as a string of paths separated by commas. When you read it,
it is not a json text! You can transform it on an array by using the explode function using the first parameter as a comma, so your $images variable will now be an array where each element is a path to an image.

Comment: This did the trick, I was deffinately mixing methods, thank you for the clarification I was goig crazy!

Answer (score 0):

Wrong use of json_decode here.

```
$myImagesFromJson = json_decode($images, true);
 foreach($myImagesFromJson as $image){
    echo $image;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well when you are inserting it you are just imploding

```
$gal_images = implode("," , $gallery_images);
```

So when you retrieve it, you just have to explode it

```
$images = explode(",",$row['images']);

foreach($images as $ima){
    echo $ima;
}
```

You dont have to use json_decode there...as its not really json data, its just comma delimitted list

```
json_decode($images);
```